# get_user_meta and update_user_meta on the same page

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, function

I have a little form that updates a custom user meta I made named "Doel":

```
<?php $user_ID = get_current_user_id(); $user_data = get_user_meta($user_ID); ?>

<form method="POST" action="" id="doel_edit">
   <input type="text" value="<?php if(isset($user_data['doel'][0])): echo $user_data['doel'][0]; endif; ?>" name="doel">
   <button value="done" type="submit" form="doel_edit">Opslaan</button>
</form>
```

When I submit the form I get the standard update_user_meta() function to run

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['doel'])) {
   update_user_meta($user_ID, 'doel', $_POST['doel']); 
} ?>
```

No this all works fine, but when the page loads after submitting the form it echo's the old value from before update_user_meta() ran. I have to reload the page by hand to get my new value.

Why doesn't the value update directly? How can I fix that?

I think running functions like these in the wp-admin works fine.

Comment: give the code inside get_user_meta function

Comment: You should be doing this via a function in *functions.php*, during an action hook.

Comment: @ aref , you can find the function here: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.1/src/wp-includes/user.php#L0 it's a core wp function

@rnevius How would I do this? I'm not sure there is a hook for either of the functions. I'm also running a similar thing where I run a custom function to save stuff with wpdb but that gives the same problem.

Comment: Or you could try with AJAX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the answer with help from somewhere else.

Because I ran get_user_meta() before update_user_meta() the values didn't update. Once I placed update_user_meta() after get_user_meta() it worked:

```
<?php $user_ID = get_current_user_id(); ?>
<?php if(isset($_POST['doel'])) {
    update_user_meta($user_ID, 'doel', $_POST['doel']); 
} ?>
<?php $user_data = get_user_meta($user_ID); ?>

<form method="POST" action="" id="doel_edit">
    <input type="text" value="<?php if(isset($user_data['doel'][0])): echo $user_data['doel'][0]; endif; ?>" name="doel">
    <button value="done" type="submit" form="doel_edit">Opslaan</button
</form>
```